# How center a movie item on a view in SDK for iPad application

Tags: objective-c, ipad, sdk, center

I need to center a movie on a view on my iPad.

Well I've used this command in xcode 4:

```
player =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                              initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:movieUrl]];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
       addObserver:self
          selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
              name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
            object:player];

[[player view] setFrame:CGRectMake(30.0, 250.0, 650.0,506.0)];
```

Now are there a way like this syntax setFrame:

```
CGRectMake(self.view.width /2, 250.0, 650.0,506.0)];
```

In other language like Actionscript I can intercept the size of my view and divide it for 2 to center an Item.

someone can help me please?

thanks

Comment: That is not correct.  UIViews do not have a width or height property directly.  You need to access that information through their frame or bounds.  view.frame.size.width or view.bounds.size.width

Comment: Ya I removed the comment thanks do not know how I forgot the frame/bounds property + Andre has the right answer down there.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what Joe said, but:

```
player.view.center = self.view.center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Andre's answer is the easiest way to center a view both vertically and horizontally.  But if you are trying to just center it in one direction access the size of your view through the values from the view's frame or bounds like so:

```
player.view.bounds.size.width
player.view.frame.size.width
```

Either will work for size.  The difference is that the bounds rectangle is measured in the view's own coordinate system so its origin is typically 0,0.  The frame is the view's rectangle in its parent view's coordinate system, so the origin is the upper left corner coordinate of your view.  Both bounds and frame typically have the same size (though in some special cases that may not be true).